# C++ rand() keeps returning the same number

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why my program keeps generating the same random digit for every round. In fact the number won't change unless I quit and restart the program. Since I'm new to C++, this should be a fairly trivial mistake that I don't know about. Below is my code and thanks in advance for your help.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int getRandNum();

int main()
{
    int randNum = getRandNum();

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

.
.
.

}

int getRandNum()
{
    int randNum;

    randNum = rand() % 3 + 1;

    return randNum;
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly lengthy code snippet with a lot of irrelevant stuff. You should try cutting it down to a minimal example that still demonstrates the problem. All the actual game logic isn't relevant to the question. And in the process you might find the problem yourself anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your `computerChoice` function only once and use this result for all the subsequent operations.

Also, the call has to be done after seeding the random generator with `srand`, like was correctly mentioned by @ZdeslavVojkovic

Answer (score 2):

You call `rand` from function `getComputerChoice()`.
However, that function is called before you set the seed with `srand`.

You need to call `srand` before the first call of `rand` function, which also means before `getComputerChoice`

Comment: Just noting that this doesn't actually solve the problem (see icepack's answer), but the order should still be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `int computerChoice = getComputerChoice();` to inside the `do` loop. The code above picks one choice at the start then never picks another.

Answer (score 0):

You just write `getComputerChoice()` below the `getPlayerChoice()`, and your issue is resolved.

```
playerChoice = getPlayerChoice();
computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your algorithm, you calling getComputerChoice() only once at the begining of the main(), but you need to do this in your do ... while:

```
...
if(playQuitOption == 'p' || playQuitOption == 'P')
    {
        cout << endl;

        playerChoice = getPlayerChoice();
        computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
...
```